# Do i need an airport transit visa?

Tags: visas, transit

I have a canadian PR card but my passport is for iran. I have flight from toronto to tehran with two stops first in london and then in frankfurt. As i checked lonon government website i don't need a visa for transitting through london due to my canada PR card. But i'm not sure if i need a visa for my stop in frankfurt, as both london and tehran are out of schengen areas so i assume i won't have to get out of international transit area in frankfurt. Also all of my flights are with lufthana and i won't be changing airports. Any help is appreciated .

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't find the answer to my question as mostly questions are about having one stop in either frankfurt or london, not two stops at both right after each other , can you please put a link of the question the answer is in?

Comment: The rules for transiting in London and in Frankfurt are independent of one another.  The requirement in London will be the same as if you were flying Toronto-London-Tehran or vice versa, and the requirement in Frankfurt will be the same as if you were flying Toronto-Frankfurt-Tehran or vice versa.  If you have specific concerns or questions related to your three-leg itinerary, you can include links to questions on transit in London and Frankfurt and explain why the answers are not sufficient in your case.